# Puma with systemd and socket activation - Errno::EADDRINUSE

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma

I have a Rails 5 app, running on puma 3.12.1, MRI 2.6.2, and Ubuntu 18.04. It used to run with `pumactl` and a custom control script but I want to configure it properly with systemd, using socket activation to have zero-downtime deployment.

The problem is that the socket holds the port and puma wants to bind on the same one so it gives this error:

```
/opt/myapp/shared/vendor/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:273:in `initialize': 
Address already in use - bind(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 3000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
```

I set it up everything according to the [puma docs](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/docs/systemd.md) and [systemd docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html).

I reloaded systemd config of course and tried to restart several times. I don't deeply understand how systemd does this socket activation but for me puma's error message seems reasonable :/

Maybe puma shouldn't try to bind on that port? But how can I communicate to puma to not bind to it but use systemd's forwarded stream?

My configuration:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/puma.socket
[Unit]
Description=Puma HTTP Server Accept Sockets

[Socket]
ListenStream=0.0.0.0:3000

# Socket options matching Puma defaults
NoDelay=true
ReusePort=true
Backlog=1024

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/puma.service
[Unit]
Description=API with Puma server
After=network.target
Requires=puma.socket

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/opt/myapp/current
ExecStart=/opt/myapp/current/script/bootup_puma
SyslogIdentifier=api-puma
PIDFile=/opt/myapp/current/tmp/pids/puma.pid
Restart=no
TimeoutSec=30
User=ubuntu

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
$ cat script/bootup_puma
#!/bin/bash

# [setting up some envvars here]

bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

```
$ cat config/puma.rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

app_dir = File.expand_path("..", __dir__)

workers ENV.fetch("API__PUMA_WORKERS", 4).to_i
threads 1, ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS", 8).to_i

bind "tcp://0.0.0.0:#{ENV.fetch('PORT', 3000)}"

pidfile "#{app_dir}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"

directory ENV.fetch("API__PUMA_DIRECTORY") unless ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV", "development") == "development"
```

As a desperate attempt, I also tried to use a unix socket instead of TCP but that ended up with a similar error despite I was being careful to not reference the socket through a symlink.

```
/opt/myapp/shared/vendor/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:367:in `add_unix_listener': 
There is already a server bound to: /opt/myapp/shared/tmp/puma.sock (RuntimeError)
```

Other useful resources I already went through:

- http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/socket-activation.html
- https://ahmet2mir.eu/blog/2015/python_ssl_sockets_and_systemd_activation/
- https://vincent.bernat.ch/en/blog/2018-systemd-golang-socket-activation

Comment: You should not have a shell script that starts puma. Move everything directly into the systemd `.service` unit and call puma (or a binstub) directly.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHampton , I cannot accept it as a solution since you wrote it as a comment but it was indeed the issue. Thanks for taking the time to review my config and pointing it out! Systemd is still like a black box for me, I'm not confident in how this socket activation works :|

Comment: I don't care that much about points, I have enough of them. It's just about helping people find their solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the intermediate shell script `bootup_puma` as Micheal Hampton pointed out in the [comments](https://serverfault.com/questions/960132/puma-with-systemd-and-socket-activation-errnoeaddrinuse#comment1249064_960132).

Changing the service to
`ExecStart=/opt/myapp/current/bin/puma -C config/puma.rb` and providing the environment with the `EnvironmentFile` directives solved the issue.

Comment: Damn, we need an intermediate shell script because of SELinux executable labelling.